# How do I change ARC setting after the project is created?

Tags: objective-c

I am new to iOS development. When I created my project, I chose the wrong setting for ARC, and now I don't know how to go back and change that setting. Where can I find that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to go under the section Build settings of the project settings and change the value of the : **Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting** property :

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Go into the Build Settings and search for "automatic reference counting" and you should see a Yes/No option.